# Ошибка при создании Image

Tags: java, swing, awt

Вот возникает такая ошибка, как ее исправить помогите пожалуйста:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero

```
ResultSet resultSet = connection.query("select url_image from "+name+" where id = "+List.get(i));
            java.sql.Blob blob = null;

            try {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    blob = resultSet.getBlob("url_image");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e4) {
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedImage destImage = null;
            try {
                destImage = ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Image scaledImage = destImage.getScaledInstance(photoLabel.getWidth(),photoLabel.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT); // вот здесь возникает ошибка
            ImageIcon imgIc = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
            photoLabel.setIcon(imgIc);
```

вот ище код из елементом Jlabel

```
 photoLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
 .addComponent(photoLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 367, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
.addComponent(photoLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
private javax.swing.JLabel photoLabel;
```

Comment: по этому фрагменту точно не скажешь - сама ошибка не тут, а с `photoLabel` - у него почему-то нулевые размеры (p.s. запускабельный фрагмент даст больше шансов на то, что тебе помогут, просто к слову)

Comment: приведите больше кода

Comment: Так что здесь не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте задать размеры photoLabel

```
JLabel photoLabel = new JLabel();
Dimension dim = new Dimension(367,367);
photoLabel.setMinimumSize(dim);
photoLabel.setMaximumSize(dim);
```